# Atom text editor on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, updates, text-editor, atom

Since I moved to Ubuntu 22.04 I have some issues with various apps and Atom text editor is one of them. Even if I somehow manage to install apps they don't work properly or  don't work at all.

I used this to install Atom but it doesn't seem to work:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget -ysudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget -y
wget -O- https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/atom.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/atom.gpg] \
https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install atom -y
atom --version
```

After trying to start Atom using terminal I got this message:

[image: screenshot of text]

Comment: I prefer `geany` editor. `atom` is slow and cumbersome.

Comment: It would help if you pasted the error messages into the question, and if you could get them to generate in English.

Comment: I suggest that you install the snap: https://snapcraft.io/install/atom/ubuntu - Additionally, please do not upload pictures of text. It's hard to read and impossible to work with. This is especially true when your system language is not English. Ask Ubuntu supports English language only at this time. Instead, change your system language to English temporarily if you need help with errors, then copy/paste the entire errors in your question and use code fences before and after the paste to preserve formatting. Don't use quotes or manipulate inside the paste

Comment: The first command you used is not a good command to use when diagnosing problems with your packages. That's because the `-y` flag will hide output from you. And the `&&` chains those two commands together. Instead run the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` separately. If these commands come back as anything but clean, post both of them to your question as there may be problems with your package management, especially if you're having problems installing other software. These commands need to run clean before you try to install anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a problem with Atom.

I know I'm not helpful, but I suggest you to try [snap app for Atom](https://snapcraft.io/install/atom/ubuntu).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have also tried this but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can install atom with snap by typing

```
sudo snap install --classic atom
```